# Database key code table

Tags: php, database, html-table, key

I have created a Table for the purpose of entering "Keys" into the database and the option of deleting them from the database It shows the table perfectly, but the problem is I can't get it to enter keys into the Database even though the details are hooked up.

```
 <?php
    define(DBUSER,"N/A");
    define(DBPWD, "N/A");
    define(DBNAME, "N/A");
    define(DBHOST, "N/A");
   $dbConn = dbconnect();


    $txt = "<table align=\"center\">";
    $txt .= "<tr><td>KeyCode</td><td>Date</td><td>Sold</td><td>Email</td></tr>";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `benkeys` where keycode = 1";

$res = mysql_query($sql, $dbConn)
or die(mysql_error());
if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)) {
}
  $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
mysql_close($dbConn);
        $cal = "js_del_key('".$row["keycode"]."'); return false;";
        $txt .= "<tr><td>".$row['keycode']."</td><td>".$row['datum']."</td>";
        $txt .= "<td>".$row['sold']."</td><td>".$row['email']."</td>";
        $txt .= "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"del\" value=\"DELETE\" onclick=\"".$cal."\"></td></tr>";

    $cal = "js_add_key(); return false;";
    $txt .= "<tr><td><input type=\"text\" size=\"46\" id=\"nkey\" /></td><td>".date("Y-m-d")."</td>";
    $txt .= "<td>N</td><td>&nbsp;</td>";
    $txt .= "<td><input type=\"button\" name=\"addkey\" value=\"ADD NEW\" onclick=\"".$cal."\"></td></tr>";
    $txt .= "</table>";
    echo $txt;
    function closeConn(){
    mysql_close();
}
    return($txt);

function p_adm_del_key($key)
{
    $link = dbconnect();
    $sql = "delete from `benkeys` where `keycode`='".$key."' limit 1";
    mysql_query($sql);
    mysql_close($link);
    return(p_adm_list_keys());
}
function p_adm_add_key($key)
{
    $link = dbconnect();
    $sql = "insert into `benkeys` (`keycode`,`datum`,`sold`) values ('".$key."','".date("Y-m-d")."','N')";
    $returnValue = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    mysql_close($link);
    return $returnValue; //This will return true/false if the query succeeded or not
}
if (p_adm_add_key('some-key')) {
    //Success!
} else {
    //Failure. ;(
}

function dbconnect()   
{
    $link = mysql_connect(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die("Could not select database: ".mysql_error());
    return($link);
}
    <?
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dbconnect()` function is referring to some constants (DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPWD, DBNAME), but I can't see them being defined anywhere. Either define them or pass them through to the function as arguments.

### Database connection

Just change the top of your script from this:

```
$username="N/A";
$password="N/A";
$database="N/A";
$host="N/A";
$dbConn = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password, $database)
    or die("Could not connect: " + mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $dbConn)
    or die("Could not find database: " + mysql_error());
```

... to this:

```
define(DBUSER,"N/A");
define(DBPWD, "N/A");
define(DBNAME, "N/A");
define(DBHOST, "N/A");
$dbConn = dbconnect();
```

### Add Key Function

```
function p_adm_add_key($key)
{
    $link = dbconnect();
    $sql = "insert into `benkeys` (`keycode`,`datum`,`sold`) values ('".$key."','".date("Y-m-d")."','N')";
    $returnValue = mysql_query($sql, $link);
    mysql_close($link);
    return $returnValue; //This will return true/false if the query succeeded or not
}
```

Then you can call the add key function like so:

```
if (p_adm_add_key('some-key')) {
    //Success!
} else {
    //Failure. ;(
}
```

Comment: Still when you try to add a key nothing happends

Comment: Ok I did that but didnt work I may of done something wrong ill update my code so you can see

Comment: What's the datatype of the `sold` field? If it's not a varchar type, you won't be able to add 'Y' or 'N'. Perhaps that is meant to be a 0 or 1?